# Automation error in global address list lookup

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to look up a person's email address using the Outlook global address list. Here is the VBA code I use to do it.

```
    'Snip
    If firstName <> "" Then
        Dim o, AddressList, AddressEntry
        Dim AddressName, Address, Address2 As String
        Set o = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set AddressList = o.Session.AddressLists("Global Address List")
        AddressName = firstName
        For Each AddressEntry In AddressList.AddressEntries
            If AddressEntry.Name = AddressName Then
                Address = AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                Exit For
            End If
        Next AddressEntry
    End If
    'Snip
```

The variable "firstName" is in the format Last name, first name. This seemingly only works half of the time I try to use it. For example if I put my own name in it work perfectly fine every time but if I put in my co-worker's name I get a little pop up bubble from Outlook saying "outlook is trying to retrieve data from the Microsoft exchange server *.com" and then I get an automation error. I couldn't find anything in common between the names that don't work and the same for those that do. Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: Another note I just thought of is that when I hit debug on the error window it highlights the "Next AddressEntry" line.

Comment: is `firstName` supposed to be the first name of a person or the first name in a list of people? Usually, it refers to the "given" or "christian" name of a single person. _Naming things is hard_

Comment: there is probably an `AddressList.AddressEntries.Count` or something similar - check your count to ensure you're getting access to more than just yourself. Also, `Address2` is a `String`, `AddressName` and `Address` are `Variant`.

Comment: @FreeMan sorry about the confusion, I have another variable called secondName that searches the address list a second time so both variables hold different full (Doe, Jane for example) names. I have also tried other names than myself and some do work. I just used myself as an example. I also tried changing address name and address to a string but that made no difference. Address2 is used in the next part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not loop through all items in GAL - some GALs contain tens of thousand of entries, and you will nto be able to loop through them.

Call `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` (returns `Recipient` object), call `Recipient.Resolve`, then use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser`.

**UPDATE**:
if the name is ambiguous, you will get back an error from `Recipient.Resolve` - Outlook Object Model does not let you recover from that - there is no way to get the list of matches and select the one you want. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use is [RDOAddressBook](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm).`ResolveNameEx` method - it returns a list of matches (of one entry if the name is not ambiguous). You can also use [RDIAddressList](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm).`ResolveName` / `ResolveNameEx` if you want to resolve against a particular container only (e.g. GAL).

```
 Set o = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 ...
 set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
 Session.MAPIOBJECT = o.Session.MAPIOBJECT
 set AdrrEntries = Session.AddressBook.ResolveNameEx("John")
 MsgBox AdrrEntries.Count & " names were returned by ResolveNameEx:"
 for each AE in AdrrEntries
     MsgBox AE.Name
 next
```

Comment: Another question about this... If 2 people in the GAL have the same name, I get an error "Cannot resolve recipient". Is there any way to make this just choose the first user it comes across? I tried using Err.Number after an on error resume next to catch it and use my old way of searching but it gives a different error number every time...

Comment: It seems it always gives a negative error number so I'll just use err.number < 0

Comment: Thanks for the update but sadly using redemption is not an option... I think I'll stick with catching the error and asking the person running the macro to manually find the user's email. It only happens every once in a while so it shouldn't be too annoying.